# How to display Bigcartel products using API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, bigcartel

I never before worked with API in Ruby on Rails so I'm pretty lost.

WHERE and HOW do I need to put this code.

```
GET http://api.bigcartel.com/mystore/products.json
```

Do I need to make a new **products** model and then write the API somewhere in application.yml

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can work with an API from ruby. First if you are lucky maybe somebody already built a wrapper for that specific API. In this case there is one [gem](https://github.com/tonkapark/bigcartel) but it does not seem to be maintained any more. It might still work so feel free to try it out.

However you can also make HTTP requests by yourself. I prefer to use [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) gem. You could define a new class in /lib directory and build an API wrapper yourself, but let's start with a simple example.

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://api.bigcartel.com/mystore/products.json')
parsed_response_body = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

So here we first create an HTTP get request, and then parse the body to turn JSON into ruby hash.

Please notice that this is a *very* minimal example that assumes that everything will always go right. APIs often fail and unexpected things happen, don't forget to catch and handle exceptions that might occur.

Comment: Thanks, what about doing this without gems?

Comment: You could use [Net::HTTP](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html), which is a Ruby library. But using a gem like HTTParty is much more convenient.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Still awaiting more useful comments